# C++ : NLopt COBYLA as compared to Matlab fmincon

Tags: c++, matlab, optimization, nlopt

I am using `NLopt library`, `COBYLA algorithm`, in C++ for minimizing a log based cost function. I have already implemented the same using `fmincom` in Matlab.
The Matlab function performs much better than `NLopt`. It requires a much smaller number of optimizations than NLopt and also converges to a minimum value much better than NLopt.

I believe that the supplementary options used for the algorithms are different. I have tried to copy the same parameters for NLopt as for the default in fmincon in Matlab and it still does not give similar results.

I need to know how to converge in a fashion similar to Matlab, if it is possible, using COBYLA in NLopt.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Why COBYLA ?
`fmincon` is afaik more like
[NLopt L-BFGS](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Algorithms#Low-storage_BFGS),
see also [LBFGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LBFGS).
They use gradient estimates,
so converge much faster than COBYLA's linear approximations when func() → quadratic.
I'd suggest

- print / plot all func values for both optimizers (print inside your function)
- post *all* options for both; COBYLA is very sensitive to rhobeg and rhoend
- try
  NLopt L-BFGS, or
  [NLopt BOBYQA](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Algorithms#BOBYQA),
  "an iteratively constructed *quadratic* approximation" .

---

Added:
[fmincom](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) uses

> "Finite differences, used to estimate gradients, are either 'forward' (default), or 'central' ..."

automatically.
You can run L-BFGS, or any gradient optimizer,
with a gradient estimator like one-sided or central differences.
In general, this may be a poor estimate for noisy functions or near boundaries;
but it works for you in fmincom, so should work in NLopt L-BFGS too.
Try that first, before spending time on completely different methods.

You'll want to set these NLopt parameters:
`initial_step` e.g. 1 or .1
`ftol_abs` and `xtol_abs` e.g. 1e-4, no smaller than you need
(for COBYLA, initial_step → rhobegin and initial_step scaled  x xtol_abs → rhoend.)

NB print the return codes from any optimizer: *why* did it stop ?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have already tried to observe/plot the values but can't draw any conclusions. COBYLA takes many more iteration and does not converge as well as fmincon(the minimized value is larger). Secondly, can you please explain all the options? I have used initial step size, but I don't really know about rho, or other options and how to use them. I tried BOBYQA as you suggested and at times it performs well but also has cases where it does converge at all! This is not the case with COBYLA on same cases. L-BFGS is not gradient free, which is needed! What do you suggest? Thanks!